# missing complete candidate for verilog-mode with company-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, verilog, system-verilog

I am using company-mode to do the auto complete in Verilog-mode. I want to write `end` and start a newline. But after I key in `end`, company-mode gives me the candidate list(`endfunction`, `endclass`, `endmodule`, `endpackage`). I have to put an extra SPACE after `end` before I press ENTER.

I am not sure how could I add `end` to that candidate list? or I should file this issue to company-mode developer or Verilog-mode developer?

Comment: I think you should file it with the company developers first.

Comment: How did you get `company-mode` working with `verilog-mode`? At http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode it looks like you need an appropriate backend for `company-mode`. Is this integrated in `verilog-mode`?

Comment: @Tobias To be honest, I have no idea how the company-mode works and I just use it for everything and it looks all good for me except the Verilog-mode. After asked question here and their github issue track, I got very very basic idea about it. Now what I do is just add verilog-keywords to company-keywords-alist. For now, it looks OK. I will test it more. If anyone can provide proper backend for it is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

company-mode doesn't support verilog-mode yet. But it can be fixed by add verilog keywords to solve this problem

```
(require 'company)
(require 'verilog-mode)
(add-to-list 'company-keywords-alist (cons 'verilog-mode verilog-keywords))
```

Hope some can create a proper backend for verilog-mode.